# Dubbio su consecutio temporum

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood, capitalization

Volevo chiederLe se fosse possibile concordare il giorno in cui io possa completare l'esame che ho sostenuto il giorno 5 luglio.

La costruzione è corretta ?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, Luigi! Potresti cercare di spiegare quali sono i tuoi dubbi su questa frase? Le domande che chiedono semplicemente "Is this text correct?" sono considerate off-topic su questo sito.

Comment: Trovo la forma *chiederLe* eccessivamente servile.

Comment: Tutta la costruzione è pesantissima e, come già detto, inutilmente servile. Non sei un villico che chiede udienza al re delle Due Sicilie ma, immagino, uno studente che scrive al professore. Nel XXI secolo è meglio qualcosa come "Dovrei completare l'esame XXX. Sarebbe possibile il giorno YYY?" Semmai, non dimenticare di iniziare e concludere come si deve (Gentile prof. ZZZ ... Un cordiale saluto, Nome Cognome; o qualcosa di analogo).

Comment: Cosa c’è di “servile” nel verbo chiederle?

Comment: @Hachi: Immagino egreg si riferisca all'uso della maiuscola in *chiederLe*.

Comment: Io trovo la frase corretta, formale ma non servile, ma non mi piace il "Le" con la maiuscola in mezzo alla parola (userei la minuscola), e non ripeterei la parola "giorno" ("...ho sostenuto il 5 luglio" è ben comprensibile).

Answer (score 4):

Essendomi spesso trovato dall'altra parte, cioè nel ruolo di docente a cui scrivono così, ecco l'impressione che faresti: sicuramente un testo così è meglio di uno sciatto o di qualcosa che sembra un messaggino su WhatsApp, ma la sensazione è che cerchi di gestire un registro linguistico che non ti è abituale e che non è affatto necessario in questa situazione.

È molto meglio se scrivi un messaggio formale, corretto, usando il lei (ma non il Lei) e in cui vai subito al dunque. Per esempio, "Dovrei completare l'esame XXX... Sarebbe possibile il giorno YYY?" Naturalmente non dimenticare di iniziare e concludere come si deve (Gentile prof. ZZZ ... Un cordiale saluto, Nome Cognome; o qualcosa di analogo).

Lo so che non era questo che volevi sentirti dire, ma se ti infili in un groviglio di congiuntivi da cui non sai come uscire (e anch'io avrei i miei dubbi), forse la conclusione più assennata è non cominciare nemmeno.

Infine, un'osservazione secondaria: la forma "volevo..." è corretta, ma può fare sorridere. Viene da pensare: "Volevi... E ora non vuoi più?"

Comment: La forma "volevo..." è un imperfetto di cortesia, non mi fa pensare a una possibile indecisione.

Comment: Sono d’accordo che in questo caso sarebbe meglio usare il condizionale, e non l’imperfetto di cortesia.

Comment: Se chi ha messo il voto negativo ha suggerimenti su come migliorare questa risposta, gliene sarò grato.