# Significato di "periodare pesantissimo"

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, adjectives

Nel racconto *Vanadio* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Eppure, rileggendo le due lettere dal **periodare pesantissimo**, infarcite di tecnicismi, non riuscivo a far tacere un dubbio, di quelli che non si lasciano accantonare e ti scricchiolano dentro come tarli.

Non sono sicura su cosa voglia dire che il "periodare" di quelle due lettere menzionate in questa frase era "pesantissimo".

Alla voce ["pesante"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pesante) del vocabolario Treccani ho trovato

> che produce un senso di noia e di molestia, perché eccessivamente serio, pedante, monotono: *una lezione, una conferenza p.*; *una direttrice p.*; *quanto sei p.!*; *che tipo p. quel tuo amico!*

E anche

> Detto di parole, modi d’agire e sim., duro, minaccioso, offensivo: *ha usato parole p. nei nostri confronti*; *il tuo intervento è stato piuttosto p.*; *giudizî, espressioni p.*; *fare p. insinuazioni su qualcuno*; di dubbio gusto, o decisamente volgare: *battuta p.*; *rivolgere p. complimenti a una donna*.

Quindi, l'espressione nel testo farebbe riferimento al fatto che quelle due lettere avevano uno stile noioso? Il significato sarebbe invece che contenevano parole dure, minacciose od offensive? Vorrebbe dire che c'erano espressioni di dubbio gusto o persino volgari? (veramente non credo che ci fossero espressioni volgari perché erano lettere di lavoro).

Ho l'impressione che il senso di "pesantissimo" nella frase sopra citata forse non corrisponda a nessuna di queste accezioni riportate dal dizionario perché ricordo come era stato usato questo aggettivo in [questo commento di @DaG](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/13055/dubbio-su-consecutio-temporum#comment31038_13055). Il significato sarebbe che c'erano costrutti nel testo che lo rendevano poco scorrevole e quindi di lettura affaticante, che produce un senso di noia?

Ecco i riferimenti a queste due lettere che appaiono nel racconto:

> Scrissi una educata lettera di protesta, esponendo i termini della questione, e pochi giorni dopo giunse la risposta: era lunga e pedante, consigliava artifici ovvi che noi avevamo già adottati senza risultato, e conteneva un’esposizione superflua e deliberatamente confusa sul meccanismo d’ossidazione della resina; ignorava la nostra fretta, e sul punto essenziale diceva soltanto che erano in corso i doverosi controlli.

> Insieme con la conferma di quest’ultimo ordine, giunse una seconda lettera, lunga quasi quanto la prima, e firmata dallo stesso Doktor L. Müller. Era un po’ piú pertinente della prima, riconosceva (con molte cautele e riserve) la giustezza della nostra doglianza, e conteneva un consiglio meno ovvio dei precedenti: «ganz unerwarteterweise», e cioè in modo del tutto inaspettato, gli gnomi del loro laboratorio avevano trovato che la partita contestata guariva se addizionata dello 0,1 per cento di naftenato di vanadio: un additivo di cui, fino a quel tempo, nel mondo delle vernici non si era mai sentito parlare.

Comment: È la costruzione dei periodi, in senso grammaticale, che è pesante. I periodi  sono  troppo lunghi e articolati. Il risultato è una lettura appesantita, affatto leggera.

Comment: “*Il significato sarebbe che c'erano costrutti nel testo che lo rendevano poco scorrevole e quindi di lettura affaticante, che produce un senso di noia?*” Sì, esattamente!! L’accezione   sarebbe la prima che citi da Treccani.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/periodare/)

> **periodare** v. intr. [der. di *periodo*] (*io perìodo*, ecc.). – Costruire il periodo o i periodi, cioè le frasi; è usato quasi esclusivam. nell’infinito sostantivato, con riferimento al modo, allo stile con cui uno scrittore costruisce i periodi: *avere un p. sciolto, agile, vivace, o pesante, stentato, contorto*, ecc.; *i prosatori del Cinquecento imitavano il p., o il modo di p., del Boccaccio; quel suo p. sinuoso, frastagliato, esasperatamente ipotattico e tentacolare* (Claudio Magris).

Lo stile della scrittura è *pesantissimo*, cioè eccessivamente pesante: quindi non scorrevole, con le frasi che sembrano macigni che si devono aggirare per capire il significato. Anche *noioso*, ma non mi sembra la prima scelta: meglio *difficile da decifrare*, anche perché *infarcito di tecnicismi*.

Si riferisce al periodare, cioè allo stile, non al significato in sé.